# Python To Read Images from Multiple Folders and Create a Large One

Tags: python, imaging

I am new to Python. I need process such a task. I have multiple test images for each unit, distributed in different subfolders.

For instance, I have multiple images

```
/folder/subfolder1/../i1.png
/folder/subfolder2/../i2.png
/folder/subfolder3/../i3.png
....
....
/folder/subfolder100/../i100.png
```

I can read all image files and create a list object. The next step is to render all of them in a matrix format 10x10, each each matrix element the particular ix.png. Prefer that below there is the caption of its own name ix.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567409/python-image-library-how-to-combine-4-images-into-a-2-x-2-grid and this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Use the `montage` command-line tool from the ImageMagick suite: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php